# Ionic 4 Modal Backdrop

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I'm attempting to fix the way my modal works when presented.

When the screen size is large it has a translucent backdrop due to the min-height css. I don't mind that min height, I just want it all to be white.

It is created normally then presented:

```
this.modalCtrl.create({
  component: AddCommentPage,
  componentProps: { id: this.place.id }
}).then((element) => element.present());
```

Here is a view when the screen is large:

[image: Large Image]

And when it is small (should be full screen):

[image: Small Image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding the following code into my .scss file:

```
  .modal-wrapper {
    background-color: white;
  }
```